# Issue with styling a select box

Tags: javascript, css, styling, drop-down-menu

I've seen plenty of post on here dealing with this but I can't quick get this right.

I'm trying to style a select box with a custom image.  The way I have it set up is setting the `opacity:0;` for the select box, setting up a div behind it with a background image, and using javascript to set the current selected value inside the div.  I have it working in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but no luck in IE.

Example 1: opacity = 0, no background image for div.  Event fires but nothing is visible.

Example 2: opacity = 0, div has my background image.  Works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, but not in IE.

Example 3: Opacity = 1, No background image for div. Event doesn't fire and normal select behavior doesn't seem to exist.

Example 4: Opacity = 1, div has my background image.  Event doesn't fire and normal select behavior doesn't seem to exist.

Note: I removed opacity:1 from examples 3 and 4 and still get the same behavior.  I am also using z-index of 50 on the select boxes and z-index of 0 on the div's to make sure they show up behind the select.  The opposite doesn't seem to provide different behavior however.

For the record, I have tried .click, .change, .live("click") .live("change") .live("click change"), .on("click"), .on("change") .on("click change") in my example #2 as far as testing it in the 4 browsers.  My ultimate question is why doesn't example 2 work in ie.  Secondary questions are what is with the opacity and its effect on the select box?  I'm assuming something with the appearence:none I have in there, but I still don't understand why opacity matters to it.  If you need me to post the acctual code I can.  But you should be able to see the javascript and css through the test page I provided.

Comment: Example 2 works fine in IE 9.

Comment: Example 2 also works fine for me in IE9. Doesn't work in IE8 and older though. Alternatively, you could put your select inside the div with the background image, as I did in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/LWJbj/ - It won't show your image in IE8 or older, but at least the select will work.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply.  Yes, now that I am home and have IE9 installed it appears example 2 works fine.  Thank you for the quick example Ana, It seems that is the best way to do what I need, if their browser supports it then all is fine, if not then default to a regular select box. Now I don't think I can check your response Ana as a solution because it's a comment.  If you can make a post reiterating what you said in the comment I will give you a check.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should nest the elements similar to

```
<div class="styled-dropdown-container">
     <select>...</select>
</div>
```

You can then add a `click` event listener on the `.styled-dropdown-container`. Events will propagete (bubble up) correctly from the dropdown and will also be simulated when the user focuses on your input manually (i.e. by tabbing through to it)